# Why Is The Orange Suggested Edit Button Insane?

Tags: support, review

I recently reached 10k rep, and suddenly, the orange button to the left of the "review" tab (which usually tells me how many suggested edits there are in the queue and is a link to that queue) is acting funny. It keeps displaying big numbers (e.g. 17 right now), but it just links to the page listing all the review queues. I don't see a total of 17 items in all of the queues combined, so I'm very confused about what the button is trying to tell me to do. I looked through the help center's page on 10k privileges, and it doesn't mention anything, and I can't find anything on meta either. Is there some feature I'm missing here or has the site simply decided to drive me mad?

(I tagged this [support](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support), since, presumably, this is presumably an undocumented feature)

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16299/19341

Answer (score 7):

It is roughly the number of all open review tasks. The reason it is not always the exact number is that it takes some time to update.

However there is another phenomenon. It differs from the numbers on the page since these are the task open for you; for example, if you have already reviewed something it does not show up for you but is taken into account for the counter since it is still an open task.

Comment: As far as I understand it's not a problem of taking time to update, but rather it displays all possible review tasks whether you can act on them or not (eg. you already reviewed a post in the closing queue but it hasn't gathered 5 votes yet).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I think both effects play a role. I only get the counter for suggested edits here, and it does happen I click on it just to arrive at a page telling me there are no tasks left;, and not because I reviewed those already. Though the effect you mention, which is discussed in my second paragraph, is what is more noticeable.

Comment: For suggested edits, I think they're simply gone too fast for you to act on them: anyone over 2k rep can act on them and gets a bright orange notification that there are reviews waiting. That's a lot of people for a comparatively small amount of tasks. I know it took me forever to get the silver badge for reviewing edits.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi let my try a different argument: would it update in (near) real time the number would change, at least  sometimes, quite frequently on somewhat busy sites. This does not seem to be the case. It does not appear to be like this, say that one could see the number count down one by one as someone works through some queue and so on. To avoid a misunderstanding: it is updated frequently, yet I claim *not* in (near) real time.